# Como enviar o comando click para uma página web com java usando bibliotecas selenium e ChromeDriver?

Tags: eclipse, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome

Como enviar o comando click para uma página web com java eclipse?, na nova versão do chromedriver.exe (ChromeDriver 111.0.5563.64) não está funcionando mais o método click()?
Baixar o chromedriver: https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads
bibliotecas para o java https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/
Codigo abaixo em arquivo controlesite.java

```
package edu.meupacote.pacote;

import java.awt.List;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.ProfilesIni;
import java.awt.List;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.protocol.about.Handler;


public class controlesite {



public static WebDriver driver=null;

public static void main(String[] args)  throws InterruptedException

{
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","driver\\chromedriver.exe");

ChromeOptions o = new ChromeOptions();
    
o.addArguments("--start-maximized");

driver = new ChromeDriver(o);

driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    
driver.get("https://www.google.com/");  
    
Thread.sleep(6000);

driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("texto da pesquisa automatizada");

Thread.sleep(2000);

driver.findElement(By.name("btnK")).click();


}
}
```

Comment: Será se estão restringindo o uso do click para automatizar navegadores afim de limitar os bots?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não encontrei nenhuma  referencia cabal para complementar a minha teoria mas a uma chance de que essa questão pode estar ligada ao acontecimento do método `click()` não está mais funcionando no novo **ChromeDriver**.
Não encontrei nenhuma citação na documentação oficial do Selenium referente.

Mas uma alternativa que pode valer é o uso do `sendKeys` .
Enviara o comando de clique para a página web

```
driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
```

Outra possível situação é que o driver do Chrome pode não  estar atualizado **ou** simples fato de que nao é `btnK` e sim pelo mesmo campo pode ser pressionado a `ENTER`

A outra maneira que simular o click.

```
driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);
```

O que diferencia um do outro é a interpretação dos navegadores.

O uso do `ENTER` é interpretado de forma diferente pelos navegadores Firefox   Chrome/Chromium, enquanto um entende que é a  `tecla Enter` para o outro é a `tecla Return` do teclado (insere uma nova linha)

Comment: Na verdade o código que eu estou usando é pra outro site, eu uso esse mesmo código com o ChromeDriver para o Chrome como com o geckodriver para o Mozilla. Nesse código eu usava perfeitamente o método click, há cerca de um ano atrás, porém tentei usar esta semana, tive que atualizar os dois drivers mas nenhum funcionou agora. vou testar as suas sugestões e falo aqui se funcionou.

Comment: Testei aqui e nenhuma desta duas proposta funcionaram

         driver.findElement(By.name("btnK")).sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);
  
       driver.findElement(By.name("btnK")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);

O mesmo código e mesma página que funcionava a um tempo atrás.

Comment: como citei    "... ou simples fato do btnK não foi encontrado."  tente dessa forma `driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);`

Comment: Obrigado, foi isso mesmo, mas alguma coisa mudou, a primeira coisa que eu tentei foi    driver.findElement(By.name("q")).click(); que antes funcionava mas agora não funciona mais, funcionou desta forma que você falou  sem usar o método click()   driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys(Keys.RETURN); este também funciou:  driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);

Comment: Valeu cardoso, assim ficou ótimo!